# Nested list in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.5

When I want to inplement the result what I expected:

A:1

B:2

C:3

A:4

B:5

C:6

And run the following code:

```
label_lst = ['A','B','C']
lst = [['1','2','3'],['4','5','6']]

for i in lst:
    for j,k in label_lst,i:
        print('{}:{}'.format(j,k))
```

The traceback output:

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Is there any module or key to fix my bug?

Comment: What do you expect `j, k` to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for sublist in lst:
    for i,j in zip(label_lst, sublist):
        print('{}:{}'.format(i,j))
```

produces

```
A:1
B:2
C:3
A:4
B:5
C:6
```

Comment: To expand on this, zip() will create tuples with pairs, triads, ... n-ads, from n iterables that you pass as arguments.